# Password for authenticating pkexec nautilus

Tags: permissions

I am running ubuntu in SSH, what should be the password for authenticating `pkexec nautilus`?

Answer (score 2):

Authenticate `pkexec nautilus` with your user password for that OS, the same password you use to run sudo commands on that OS.

`pkexec PROGRAM` allows an authorized user to execute `PROGRAM` as another user. If username is not specified, then the program will be executed as the administrative super user, root. pkexec will use the authentication agent registered for the calling process. However, if no authentication agent is available, then pkexec will register its own textual authentication agent.