# authentication failed

Tags: permissions

polkit-agent-helper-1: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

I am getting this error after giving the password for authentication

Comment: Please give us some more details, such as what you are attempting to do, and what kind of environment you're in.

Comment: i am trying to run "pkexec nautilus" this code

Comment: [Edit] your question to include new information. Is this a system you installed yourself? Are there more than one user account? Which Ubuntu version are you using? Are you [trying to run nautilus on a remote system via SSH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152824/password-for-nautilusi-am-running-ubuntu-in-ssh-what-should-be-the-password-for) [Edit] your question to provide answers to this.

Comment: Related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152824/password-for-nautilusi-am-running-ubuntu-in-ssh-what-should-be-the-password-for ?

Comment: system is mine itself.  no other person is using my account . i am using 16.04 ubuntu. i am using SSH

Comment: IIRC the default policykit configuration does not permit *remote* users to escalate privileges in this way

Comment: @steeldriver interesting information ! Can you point to any more details? Thank you!